How to combine conditions in seq-logging
I want to find all logs between two dates however this search does not work
@Timestamp > DateTime(concat('2024-06-19 19:00', 'Z')) and @Timestamp < DateTime(concat('2024-06-19 19:20', 'Z'))

if I use only this query I see results
@Timestamp > DateTime(concat('2024-06-19 19:00', 'Z'))

How do I combine multiple conditions in the search?
The only way I was able to get what I want is by using the "date selector" like this

However I want to be able to use it in a query.

Does it work when you select a date way into the future (ie next year) for the second part of the query?

@Caramiriel no it does not

@Caramiriel I added more details

Your query looks fine to me (and works for me in Seq). Check that you aren't filtering out events with a selected signal, and that you don't also have a conflicting date range selected.
If that doesn't work make sure you are on the latest version of Seq.

select ToIsoString(@Timestamp) as Date, @Timestamp, if @Data.reqBody.source.campaign.name is not null then @Data.reqBody.source.campaign.name else @Message from stream where @Timestamp > 638543137183070000 - 1m and @Timestamp < 638543137183070000 + 1m and (Contains(@Document, 'email@gmail.com') or @Message like '%sending%') and @Data.endTime is null order by Date desc -> this query works but I still can not easily transform string into date

The is not null then bit can be replaced with the coalesce function (https://docs.datalust.co/docs/scalar-functions#coalescearg0-arg1-).
DateTime transforms strings into timestamps.
